# Tomcat can not find xxx.jsp when using domain name

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I tried to visit the web pages that deployed under **Tomcat**, the file directory is as below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaa7a.png)

when I use http://127.0.0.1:8080/jw20180503/ to visit the index.html, and then I enter the account and password, then click Login button, it successfully link to 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/jw20180503/admin/managerindex.jsp .
However, when I use my domain name to visit it, I can only visit the index.html and when I enter the account and password and then click Login, I got a HTTP 404 page. It has been bothering me for days, but I haven't found a solution yet. Any tips will be appreciated!
By the way, the cloud hosting is Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Comment: sounds like a dns issues, try open the browser console CTRL-SHIFT-J on chrome and check for error messages there. it may also be something related to CORS which also can be recognized using the browser console

Comment: what is the url when you get the 404?

Comment: it wad because that I haven't release 8080 port in my security group